# react-navigation: How to run my function when a Tab is pressed?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I would like to load my own function when clicking on a tab. So instead of loading the tab's screen, it should load my (tested and working) function that allows you to pick an image from the iOS simulator gallery. This tab 'AddImage' sits in between the 'Home' and 'Settings' tab. I don't need to switch to any other tab, just on clicking the 'AddImage' tab icon, run my function openGallery().

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Platform, Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, CameraRoll, Image } from 'react-native';
    import { Alert, Button } from 'react-native-elements';
    import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
    import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
    import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';      



            //Empty AddImage Screen
            export class AddImage extends Component{

             constructor(props) {
               super(props);

             this.openGallery = this.openGallery.bind(this);
            }
               openGallery(){
                    //execute function.......
               }

           componentDidMount(){
           this.props.navigation.setParams({openGallery: this.openGallery.bind(this)})
   }
            }

            export default createBottomTabNavigator({

                 Home: { screen: Home, 
                  navigationOptions:{
                      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
                      tabBarIcon: ({tintColor})=>(<Icon name="home" color={tintColor} size={24}/>)
                  }
                },
            AddImage: { screen: () => null, 
              navigationOptions:{
               tabBarLabel: '',
               tabBarIcon: ({tintColor})=>(<Icon name="plus-square" color={tintColor} size={24}/>),
               tabBarOnPress: () => { this.openGallery() },
      }
    },

                Settings: { screen: Settings,
                  navigationOptions:{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
                    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor})=>(<Icon name="cog" color={tintColor} size={24}/>)
                  }  
                 },
            },

            {//other bottom tab configurations
              order: ['Home', 'AddVideo', 'Settings'],
              }
            });
```

How do I achieve this? I'm trying to use the 'tabBarOnPress' navigation option which belongs to the component, but it's not working and wont let me call my own defined function. Or is there another way entirely? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try declaring the `openGallery` function on the same file as the navigator and change the AddImage part to this:

```
AddImage: { screen: () => null, 
  navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel: '',
      tabBarIcon: ({tintColor})=>(<Icon name="plus-square" color={tintColor} size={24}/>),
      tabBarOnPress: () => { this.openGallery() },
  }
},
```

Comment: It seems to have trouble recognising openGallery() as a function when being called in tabBarOnPress. All of the code above is in my App.js for now, but im assuming the function openGallery() must be declared in a class? So i tried adding it within this class but no luck:


export class AddImage extends Component {

  this.openGallery = this.openGallery.bind(this);
}

Comment: Apologies, as im new to the forum. Code in this comments section isn't coming out right. i'll try again...

Comment: Edit the original question. Paste the entire App.js code.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't let the user move to the next screen and at that screen, you set a function Picker at the Constructor. So it means it will automatically load your function picker when the user clicks on tab AddImage.

And you can add the navigate back to the homepage when user success adds an image or cancel pick image. Otherwise, if you want to send the URL of the image back to the homepage, just use params.

This approach is easier.

For example at Add Image screen:

```
constructor(props){
 super(props)
 this.openGallery()
}
```

And this UI will make sense for user cause when clicking the add button on the navigation, it will highlight the button.

Comment: Yes, that would make perfect sense, but i get an error: "inst.render is not a function". It's perhaps not the best way to execute it (like missing a binding or declaration somewhere?)

Comment: Just check your code again and let me know the result, it should work cause if you place your code at constructor, it will run your function before the render.  Or you can move it to the componenDidMount, I think it will be better for UI when user see the screen first and then load the picker.

Comment: How do i add this correctly to the componentDidMount? I've edited the original post... however, think of the Tab's icon as just a button to load my openGallery(). I have nothing to render on the actual AddImage tab itself

Comment: And if you use this lib: react-native-image-picker. Use this function to open the picker directly: 
    // Open Image Library:
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
    // Same code as in above section!
    });

Comment: Thanks, i got this working. The function now loads on clicking the tab, putting it in the compnentDidMount(). Very slow to load and cancel, and on subsequent clicks of the tab, doesn't reload the openGallery(). Does this have to somehow link to the tab event, tabBarOnPress()?

Comment: I don't know why it is slow but to fix the "subsequent clicks of the tab", it because the state doesn't change so it doesn't re-render ==> not run the function again. So you can pass a params: isOpenGalary: true to this component. And then use setState to re-render the component.

Comment: If it fix your problem, would you mind to accept my answer? Thanks mate